# Opening Excel ODBC connection from C#

Tags: c#, excel, odbc

I'm looking to create a process that opens several excel files and just refreshes them. I have code:

```
   excel.Visible = true;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("Testfile.xlsx");

    workbook.RefreshAll();
    workbook.Save();
```

The issue is that because on these worksheets the connections are set to refresh in the background it is trying to save before it has finished refreshing. I know i need to set BackgroundQuery = false, but I don't know how to access the already existing connections. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't manage to get this specific code to work, but by trial and error I figured out that:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookConnection i in workbook.Connections)
        { System.Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
        i.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = false;
        }
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much C, so the syntax may be wrong, but it's the worksheet.querytable object that you want:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = workbook.worksheets(1)
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet qt = ws.querytables(1)

ws.QueryTables(1).RefreshOnFileOpen = False
ws.QueryTables(1).BackgroundQuery = False
```

Comment: So I didn't manage to get this specific code to work, but by trial and error I figured out that: 
        
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookConnection i in workbook.Connections)
        { System.Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
        i.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = false;
        }

works.